# Which of this two has a better performance in PHP and why?

Tags: php, class, static

I have a static method defined in a class as follows:

```
class SomeEpicClass {

    public static function iDoCrazyThings($param)
    {
       //All The Matrix computations occurring here
    }
}
```

Now, I have two options for calling this method:

**CASE 1**

```
$instance = new SomeEpicClass();

$results1 = $instance->iDoCrazyThings(3.14159265);
$results2 = $instance->iDoCrazyThings(9.8);
```

**CASE 2**

```
 $results1 = SomeEpicClass::iDoCrazyThings(3.14159265);
 $results2 = SomeEpicClass::iDoCrazyThings(9.8);
```

**Which of these cases has a better performance and why, please?**

Comment: Test it. Time them yourself.

Comment: If method is static, then call it statically. As for performance, it will depend on how many calls you are making to it. Pinching milliseconds is pointless

Comment: put this question here:- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: CASE 2,static method you cannot use in PHP7.In PHP 7, calling non-static methods statically is deprecated, and will generate an E_DEPRECATED warning. Support for calling non-static methods statically may be removed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to know what is better is check this out.

First static methods are nothing more than namespaced global functions.

When you should use the static method?:

> when method is free of side effects.

The main adventage are:

> this method will work still in the same way
>   you can use it without create a object